# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command error installing mongo-connector using pip command

Tags: python, mongodb, pip

I tried installing mongo-connector using following command prompt:

```
pip install mongo-connector
```

It threw error :

'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Please post the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `easy_install pip` or [install `pip` manually](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).

Answer (score 0):

pip is a package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python.Most distributions of Python come with pip pre-installed.

Just set the environment PATH variable pointing to python application and to pip folder, pip generally resides in Scripts folder

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Python27\;C:\python27\Scripts"
```

Thanks